# pg_get_serial_sequence not recognizing table name

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, sql-insert, auto-increment

I'm attempting to get the last `SERIAL ID` created in a table by using`pg_get_serial_sequence()` in a procedure, but I keep getting an error:

> [42P01]ERROR: relation "user" does not exist
>
> Where: SQL function "insert_new_user" statement 2

The `User` table certainly exists, as I can `SELECT` from it.

Below is the DDL script for creating the 2 tables being effected by my function:

```
CREATE TABLE users.User
(
    ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    EmailAddress TEXT,
    ROWCREATE_TS TIMESTAMP,
    IS_ACTIVE BOOLEAN,
    INACTIVE_TS TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE users.Credential
(
    CredentialValue TEXT,
    UserId INT REFERENCES users.User(ID)
);
```

And here is the procedure that is returning the error:

```
/**
  Creates a new user
 */
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE users.INSERT_NEW_USER(userName TEXT, emailAddress TEXT, password TEXT)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    INSERT INTO users.User
    (
        NAME,
        EmailAddress,
        ROWCREATE_TS,
        IS_ACTIVE
    )
    SELECT
        INSERT_NEW_USER.userName,
        INSERT_NEW_USER.emailAddress,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        TRUE
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT TRUE
            FROM users.User
            WHERE
                NAME = INSERT_NEW_USER.userName
        );

    INSERT INTO users.Credential
    (
        CREDENTIALVALUE,
        USERID
    )
    VALUES
    (
        INSERT_NEW_USER.password,
        (SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('user', 'id')))
    );
$$;
```

(NOTE: Before someone mentions it - I do not plan on storing passwords here in plain text.)

What can I do differently to either address this issue of `pg_get_serial_sequence` not recognizing the `User` table, or to ultimately get that last created ID stored into a usable variable that I can pass into my `INSERT INTO users.Credential` statement?

Comment: `user` us a reserved keyword. you need to quote it: `"User"` - but it would be better if you find a different name

Comment: "user" is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL. You can have tables and columns named "user" and also "User", but you'd have to always double-quote those names and always use the same case. It's better to avoid them altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It wasn't enough to rename the table, I also had to use the fully qualified name, as @clamp suggested. I had tried this before with the table named as `User`, and that still didn't cut it. So, again, renaming the table AND using the full qualified path solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by using a combination of suggestions in the comments.

I had renamed the table, as `User` is a PostgreSQL keyword, and also used the fully qualified name `users.NewTableName` within the `pg_get_serial_sequence()` call, as shown below.

`SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('users.NewTableName', 'id'))`.

EDIT: It could be worth pointing out, for future readers with a similar issue, that the following also worked as a fix to my goal of getting that ID down to the 2nd statement. I was able to do it using `WITH`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE users.INSERT_NEW_USER(userName TEXT, emailAddress TEXT, password TEXT)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    WITH Inserted as(
        INSERT INTO users.Users
        (
            NAME,
            EmailAddress,
            ROWCREATE_TS,
            IS_ACTIVE
        )
        SELECT
            INSERT_NEW_USER.userName,
            INSERT_NEW_USER.emailAddress,
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            TRUE
        WHERE
            NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT TRUE
                FROM users.Users
                WHERE
                    NAME = INSERT_NEW_USER.userName
            )
        RETURNING ID
    )

    INSERT INTO users.Credential
    (
        CREDENTIALVALUE,
        USERID
    )
    VALUES
    (
        INSERT_NEW_USER.password,
        (SELECT Inserted.ID FROM Inserted)
    );
$$;
```

With that said, I would also like to advise readers that they should avoid using PostgreSQL keywords for naming tables, variables, etc.